# Ultimate SEO Module + htaccess 301 .html redirect issue

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, zen-cart

I have successfully installed the Ultimate_SEO_URLs_v2.103 to my shopping cart installation (which is v1.36).

We are getting ready to go live with the site but I need to redirect html pages that are indexed by google to the new html page names.

The problem that I am having is trying to redirect pages with .html extensions to the page names that are rewritten by the htaccess file fromUltimate SEO URL.

It works if I use .htm page for the original page and redirect to the new counterpart page.

Here is the code I am using in .htaccess file (after Ultimate SEO rewrite code):

```
redirect 301 /old_conditions.html domain.com/conditions.html
```

so if you go to http://domain.com/old_conditions.html I want it to redirect to http://domain.com/conditions.html

It doesn't work, it goes to the page can not be found page!

Can someone please help me figure out why I can't get a redirect from a .html page when using the Ultimate SEO URL module?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess using `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule ^44-wholesale-celosia\.html$ /flowers/celosia.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

Also make sure **this rule is right at top just below `RewriteBase /`** line.

Comment: It not worked for me. I am using Zen-Cart and Ultimate SEO URL plugin. I want to change my old url structure and want if someone click any old url link it will redirected to a new one. But some how redirection occurs except file name which contain .html extension. I want to redirect .html old file to a new .html file. But I can't.

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://domain.com/old_conditions.html` in browser? Make sure this is very first rule in your .htaccess.

Comment: I write the following code in my htaccess RedirectMatch 301 ^/44-wholesale-celosia\.html$ /flowers/celosia.html and it shows me only http://wholesaleflowersinc.com/flowers not http://wholesaleflowersinc.com/flowers/celosia.html

Comment: When I entered `http://wholesaleflowersinc.com/44-wholesale-celosia.html` in my browser it became: `http://wholesaleflowersinc.com/flowers/celosia.html?main_page=44-wholesale-celosia`

Comment: Yes, for my browser may be it show due to the cache problem. However, why the redirection is not happen? This is happen only for .html case otherwise all redirection successfully occurs except .html file extension

Comment: Didn't get your comment. Can you post your full .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Suppose I category name is celosia which old url format is 44-wholesale-celosia.html and I change this format to celosia.html. But after change this format if someone click on the old url I want to redirect it to a new URL. But Redirection is not occur properly with the extension .html . If I put the 44-wholesale-celosia it will redirect properly to celosia.html but not 44-wholesale-celosia.html to celosia.html . Does it make any sense?

Comment: I asked you to post your full .htaccess so that I can check and give you better answer.

Comment: My htaccess is too long, I can't post it in a comment box. From where I will post the code?

Comment: You can post it on pastebin.com site and provide me link.

Comment: Yes, the link is http://pastebin.com/khf0PDsG , Please check the code and please help me

Comment: Ok updated rule, make sure this rule is right at top just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: I don't understand, will you please update the file and paste it in pastebin.com